# how to add product to cart from a search container html/css/js

Tags: javascript, html, css, search, cart

I am trying to prevent the search container from closing when clicking the `add-to-cart` button in the search results.

Adding the selected product or a cloned product to the cart when clicking the add to cart button.

I have added an event listener to the search icon `#search-btn` to toggle the visibility of the search form and hide the search container when opening the form.

Implemented the `performSearch` function to handle the search functionality. It clears previous search results, iterates through the product boxes, and displays the matching products in the search container.

For each matching product, we clone the product box, append it to the search container, and attach an event listener to the add-to-cart button within the cloned product.

In the event listener for the add to cart button, we prevent the event from propagating to the parent elements (including the search container), ensuring that the container doesn't close when clicking the button. Inside the event listener, we extract the product name and price from the clicked product box, create a new cart item object, add it to the cart, and update the cart UI.
and it still doesn't work.

```
let searchForm = document.querySelector('.search-form');
let searchInput = searchForm.querySelector('input');
let productSlider = document.querySelector('.product-slider');
let searchContainer = document.querySelector('.search-container');

// Toggle the search form on search icon click
document.querySelector('#search-btn').onclick = () => {
  searchForm.classList.toggle('active');
  searchContainer.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the search container when opening the search form
};

const performSearch = () => {
  const searchTerm = searchInput.value.toLowerCase();
  const productBoxes = productSlider.querySelectorAll('.box');

  // Clear previous search results
  searchContainer.innerHTML = '';

  // Iterate through the product boxes and display matching product(s)
  productBoxes.forEach((box) => {
    const productName = box.querySelector('h3').textContent.toLowerCase();
    if (productName.includes(searchTerm)) {
      const clonedBox = box.cloneNode(true);
      searchContainer.appendChild(clonedBox);

      // Get the add to cart button in the cloned product
      const addToCartBtn = clonedBox.querySelector('.btn');

      // Prevent closing the search container when clicking the add to cart button
      addToCartBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        const productBox = event.target.closest('.box');
        const productName = productBox.querySelector('h3').innerText;
        const productPrice = productBox.querySelector('.price').innerText;

        // Create a new cart item object
        const item = {
          name: productName,
          price: productPrice,
        };

        // Add the item to the cart
        cartItems.push(item);

        // Update the cart UI and total
        updateCartUI();
        updateCartTotal();
      });
    }
  });

  // Display message if no search results found
  if (searchContainer.children.length === 0) {
    const noResultsMsg = document.createElement('p');
    noResultsMsg.textContent = 'No matching products found.';
    searchContainer.appendChild(noResultsMsg);
  }

  // Show the search container and apply active state to the search form
  searchContainer.style.display = 'flex';
  searchForm.classList.add('active');
};

// Perform search on input change
searchInput.addEventListener('input', performSearch);

// Perform search on form submission
searchForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  performSearch();
});

// Hide the search container and remove active state from the search form
searchForm.addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {
  // Check if the focusout event target is within the container or its children
  if (
    event.relatedTarget &&
    (searchContainer.contains(event.relatedTarget) || searchForm.contains(event.relatedTarget))
  ) {
    return; // Do not close if the related target is within the container or form
  }

  searchContainer.style.display = 'none';
  searchForm.classList.remove('active');
});

// Prevent closing when clicking inside the container or form
searchContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

searchForm.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: It's hard to imagine what your code is doing without "looking" at it. You'll need to create a snippet that can be used by people to help answer your question. You can do this by either adding the HTML, CSS necessary to your question (using the code snippet), or recreate your problem on https://codesandbox.io/ and share the link in your question.